# Deserializing a string in C

Tags: c, strtok

I've data being sent in the following format

```
1 2 5
1 3 6
1 4 9
```

I'm deserializing them using the following function

```
 void deserialize(RV** arr, char* msg){
        int idx = 0;
        char* line = strtok(msg, "\n");
        RV rv;
        rv.server1 = atoi(strtok(line, " "));
        rv.server2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        rv.weight = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        memcpy(arr[idx], &rv, sizeof(rv));
        idx++;

        while (strtok(NULL, "\n") != NULL){
            //printf("%s\n", line);
            RV rv;
            rv.server1 = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            rv.server2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            rv.weight = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            memcpy(arr[idx], &rv, sizeof(rv));
            idx++;
        }

    }
```

This returns the first line correctly, but the rest are all 0

```
1 2 5
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

What am I doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use a debugger and go through your code step by step. Or add lots of status reporting `printf`'s to your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the problems you are having is that the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is not reentrant, which means you can't use it to tokenize two different strings. If you have `strtok_s` you could use it, or you could use simple [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) parsing on each line.

Another problem is that you don't get the new line in the loop.

---

You could easily replace your code with something like this:

```
int deserialize(RV** arr, char* msg)
{
    char *line = strtok(msg, "\n");
    int idx = 0;

    do
    {
        sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &arr[idx]->server1, &arr[idx]->server2, &arr[idx]->weight);
        ++idx;
    } while ((line = strtok(NULL, "\n")) != NULL);

    return idx;  // Return the number of lines we parsed
}
```

This assumes that there is at least one line (ending with a newline) in the message. Also note that I wrote the code of the top of my head, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Worked like a breeze. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should also check that `sscanf` returns `3`, the contents of the array entry fields have indeterminate contents for a line that does not match.